# Stop jQuery from repeating, example attached

Tags: jquery, repeat

I have to attach a jQuery to an invoice. Sometimes I have to print multiple invoices as once in a batch. When this happens my exact same jQuery appears for every invoice and it runs each time creating extra elements I do not need. Is there a way to have a jQuery that appears more then once only run once when it is the last time it appears in the code? Thanks for any help.

Example is below. I have previously posted this and everyone asked to see how I was doing it. I was not sure how to add the code to the post as it said it was too long. Thanks for all your help. You guys are awesome.

```
<table width=180 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                <tr> 
                  <td class="barcode_needed">10133</td>
                </tr>

<!--This section of code is attached to every order so it repeats when each order prints, (this is a simplified version of the code, I need to make it only run the last time it shows up-->                    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://barcode-coder.com/css/style.css?ft=1298939919" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js"></script>


<script>
$('td.barcode_needed').append('<div class="bcTarget">');

$('.bcTarget').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.barcode(
    'G' + $this.closest('td.barcode_needed').text(),
    'code128'
);
});


</script>
<!--End Repeating Code-->
                <tr> 
                  <td class="barcode_needed">20133</td>
                </tr>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://barcode-coder.com/css/style.css?ft=1298939919" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js"></script>


<script>
$('td.barcode_needed').append('<div class="bcTarget">');

$('.bcTarget').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.barcode(
    'G' + $this.closest('td.barcode_needed').text(),
    'code128'
);
});


</script>

                <tr> 
                  <td class="barcode_needed">30133</td>
                </tr>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://barcode-coder.com/css/style.css?ft=1298939919" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js"></script>


<script>
$('td.barcode_needed').append('<div class="bcTarget">');

$('.bcTarget').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.barcode(
    'G' + $this.closest('td.barcode_needed').text(),
    'code128'
);
});


</script>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your repeating template to include a check:

```
<script>
if (typeof alreadyDone === "undefined") {
   var alreadyDone = true;

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('td.barcode_needed').append('<div class="bcTarget">');

     $('.bcTarget').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.barcode('G' + $this.closest('td.barcode_needed').text(),'code128');
     });    
   });
}
</script>
```

Now it should run only once.

Another thing to try, where we remove the classes as we go...

```
<script>
 $('td.barcode_needed').each(function() {
       $(this).append('<div class="bcTarget">');
 });

 $('.bcTarget').each(function() {
   $(this).barcode('G' + $(this).closest('td.barcode_needed').text(),'code128');
   $(this).removeClass('bcTarget');       
   $(this).closest('td.barcode_needed').removeClass('barcode_needed');
 });    
</script>
```

Comment: That is the problem,  I can't add anything only once.  Whatever code I put it in will repeat with every order that is being batched.  The code has to be attached to a single order page.

Comment: when I am running it, not bar codes are printing at all anymore.  I have cut and pasted the code.  any ideas?

Comment: @user764728 I updated it again, please try it, but.. question.. maybe this needs to run at the end after everything has loaded?

Comment: It is still failing.  It isn't allowing any of them to run. and yes it does need to run at the end.  all I want is the last instance of the jquery to run

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {, if I remove this part, then the barcodes show up again, but they show up multiple times

Comment: is there a way to attach a counter and every time it sees the function it can add one.  when the counter reaches its highest number then it runs the script?

Comment: @user764728 I had a syntax error that I just fixed..  do you know how many times it will appear?  How would we know the highest number?

Comment: It can appear an infinite amount of times.  I can cap it if we need to and allow to only print in batches of 100 or 50 or some number or less if that is needed.

Comment: @user764728 Check out the edit I just made.. another method to try that cleans up after itself.

Comment: that is so close.  the only thing now is it isn't returning the barcode number that is needed.  It it returns the G, but not the number from barcode_needed as the class is removed

Comment: @user764728 I made a ninja edit after posting it... take a look now, I moved the td class removal to the end.

Comment: can I attach a number to the class and have it constantly add 1 and change barcode_needed+1 and so on for each new function based on the last.

Comment: That is awesome.  You have just made my day. Thank you so much